# Issue loading PDF in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I am trying to load a pdf in UIwebView but it does not scale page to fit. Moreover it shows 2 pages at a time. Can someone suggest a better way to open a pdf(in the bundle) in ipad just like a reader?

thanks.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but does your PDF effectively contain single pages? In other words, if you open it in Adobe Reader, can you look at what you consider to be a single page at a time or does it also provide a dual-page view?

Answer (score 0):

Is this line of code included?

```
webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Comment: Yes. It is very much included. Still... Does not scale itself.